# How to Doxygen comment generated code

Tags: c++, c, doxygen, c-preprocessor

I'm using the C preprocessor to generate elements in an enum. Is there a way to write doxygen comments for the generated elements? I can't just run it through the preprocessor before doxygen since that will strip the doxygen comments.

Example:

```
#define ATTRIBUTES \
X(TITLE,    "title") \
X(FILENAME, "filename") \
X(GENRE_ID, "genre_id")

enum ATTRIBUTES_ENUM {
  #define X(a, b) a##_ATTRIBUTE,
  ATTRIBUTES
  #undef X
  ATTRIBUTES_COUNT
};
```

And adding something like:

```
/**
 * \def TITLE_ATTRIBUTE
 * The media's title.
 */
```

doesn't work.

**EDIT**
Thanks to Thomas Matthews, here's the solution I used:

```
#define ATTRIBUTES \
X(TITLE,    "title")    /*!< title attribute */ \
X(FILENAME, "filename") /*!< filename attribute */ \
X(GENRE_ID, "genre_id") /*!< genre id attribute */

#define X(a, b) a##_ATTRIBUTE,

enum ATTRIBUTES_ENUM {
  ATTRIBUTES
  ATTRIBUTES_COUNT
};

#undef X
```

And tell Doxygen to expand macros. The only downside is that the comment for the last element is also used as the comment for the `ATTRIBUTES` define. But that's a minor issue in my case.

Comment: It's possible you could abuse the ## operator to generate a // token - but you'd be in the realm of undefined behaviour. The problem is that comments are deleted in translation phase 3, before macros are expanded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following

1. In the Doxygen configuration file, tell it to process the macros.
2. In the macro definition, add the Doxygen comments after each member:

   ```
   #define ATTRIBUTES \  
   X(TITLE, "title") /**!< title element */ \  
   X(FILENAME, "filename") /**!< file name element */ \  
   X(GENRE_ID, "genre_id") /**!< title element */
   ```

*Due to code formmatting issues, the comments on each line should be C sytle comments.*

My understanding is that Doxygen should process the macro (making the substitutions), then feed the modified text into it's comment engine.

Just a guess though.

I highly suggest a different schema for converting enums to text.  Use either an array, vector or map.  Such as:

```
enum Attributes_Enum
{
  TITLE, FILENAME, GENRE
};

struct Enum_Text_Entry
{
    enum Attributes_Enum value;
    const char * text;
};

Enum_Text_Entry  Enum_To_Text[] =
{
    {TITLE, "title"},
    {FILENAME, "filename"},
    {GENRE, "genre"},
};

const unsigned int NUMBER_OF_ENTRIES =
sizeof(Enum_To_Text) / sizeof(Enum_To_Text[0]);
```

Now just search the table for an enum and read the text out.  The nice thing about putting the enum value and the text together in a structure is that this allows the enum values to change, but the rest of the code doesn't have to change.

Comment: Nice, that worked! I had to play around with that a bit and move the `#define` out of the `enum` definition. In our case, I believe the thinking was that a linear search through the list of attributes would be undesirable because it ends up in a tight loop. It's a good point though - using the preprocessor like this is sort of messy.